# Is this extended acl valid?

Tags: cisco, access-control

**Permit tcp any eq 80 host 10.23.3.10 eq 80**

I would like to permit any address to reach the host 10.23.3.10 strictly on port 80

This is a school lab exercise. The question goes, for inbound traffic initiated on the outside network, allow everyone to access only ICMP and HTTP to host 10.23.x.10 All other traffic initiated from outside network must be denied.

```
Ip access-list extended forext
Permit icmp any host 10.23.3.10
Permit tcp any eq 80 host 10.23.3.10 eq 80
Deny ip any any
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `any eq 80` filters for the source port - applying that to a HTTP client makes it near impossible to connect to the server. HTTP clients use ephemeral source ports (49152-65535).

Since you don't know a client's source port you can only filter by destination port

```
permit tcp any host 10.23.3.10 eq 80
```